# gulp-sass imagePath not working

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm trying to prefix my images in my scss files, for example in my scss file I have

```
background-image: image-url('/img/bg.png')
```

which should be transformed in the css file to

```
background-image: url('/barfoo/img/bg.png');
```

In my gulpfile.js I have my styles task defined as follows:

```
var _sass = gulp.src('../scss/main.scss')
    .pipe($.sass({
        errLogToConsole: true,
        imagePath: '/barfoo/'
    }))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer('last 2 versions'));
```

The problem is now that when I run this task and check the generated css file I get

```
background-image: url('/img/bg.png')
```

No prefixed path. I don't get any errors. Any suggestions what might go wrong here ?

Answer (score 2):

I think, you should apply another gulp plugin after compiling sass to css:

checkout this:
https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-css-url-adjuster/